# How to include a comma in swagger field - not csv

Tags: json, swagger-ui

I'm having a hard time finding the escape code to use to include a comma in a request in Swagger UI. It is to catch if the money/decimal format is using comma instead of dot.

```
{
  "applicationReceivedDate": "2020-09-10",
  "contributionAmt": 500","00,
  "countryCd": 900,
  "creditablePeriodId": 1,
  "individualId": 112,
  "programCd": 1,
  "thirdCountryInd": false,
  "totalCreditableYears": 26
}
```

I have tried many escape characters but haven't been successful.

Currently it shows:

```
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:1970/cp/" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{      \"applicationReceivedDate\": \"2020-09-10\",      \"contributionAmt\": 500\",\"00,      \"countryCd\": 900,      \"creditablePeriodId\": 1,      \"individualId\": 112,      \"programCd\": 1,      \"thirdCountryInd\": false,      \"totalCreditableYears\": 26    }"
```

Comment: `"contributionAmt": 500","00` is not valid JSON. Did you mean `"contributionAmt": "500,00"`?

Comment: yes after much reading over the weekend i know its not really valid -- was hoping there was some trick or hack to include a comma inside a number but havent been able to do it. there must be a way to do it with inernational currency though. maybe in the setup of swagger -- im assigned the task of doing validation but cant get the comma to make it through